# Configure Guest account so user can't browse the Program Files folder

Tags: windows-xp, security

**On Windows XP, how do you configure the/a Guest account so the user can't browse the `C:\Program Files` folder at all?**

However, they can still run programs contained in that folder (if shortcuts are provided on their desktop)?

Answer (score 0):

First open explorer, go to Folder Options > View and uncheck the Use simple file sharing, this will show the security tab.

Just log in with your admin account, right click on the folder, go to security, add the guest account and uncheck the permissions, (or you could deny everything and that means that he can't run the programs). In your case just leave read and execute

Comment: Read and execute means they can read and therefore copy.  I am trying to avoid having them be able to copy it to another disk.

Comment: then deny it, or you can try Folder Guard (http://www.winability.com/folderguard/)

Comment: @JohnB: Add a new ACL rule that denies read access to `Program Files` itself but not to its contents.

Comment: @JohnB: How do you expect an account to run a program if it can't read the binary code from disk?